# looking local file system instead of hdfs when I ran the spark submit

Tags: apache-spark

when I ran the spark-submit, it throw error indicating that no file in the file system as below.

```
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.hadoop.mapred.InvalidInputException: Input path does not exist: file:/user/sclee/clustering2/mapTemplate_micron
```

I think that my file is on the hdfs not in the my local system.
I found that my hadoop configuration file was correctly configured as below

```
<property>
<name>fs.defaultFS</name>
<value>hdfs://spark.dso.hdm1:9000</value>
</property>
<property>
```

How to resolve this issue?

### supplement

Below is my submit query.
Actually, I used the spark well using below query. However, I mistakenly removed the spark directories. So I copied the spark directory from worker node. And then my issue occurred. I hope to fix my issue. Thanks.

```
hadoop fs -rm -r /home/hawq2/*
spark-submit \
        --class com.bistel.spark.examples.yma.ClusterServiceBasedOnNewAlgo \
        --master spark://spark.dso.spkm1:7077 \
        --executor-memory 8g\
        --executor-cores 4\
        --jars /home/jumbo/user/sclee/clustering/guava-19.0.jar\
        --conf spark.eventLog.enabled=true\
        --conf spark.eventLog.dir=hdfs://spark.dso.hdm1:9000/user/jumbo/applicationHistory\
        --conf spark.memory.offHeap.enabled=true\
        --conf spark.memory.offHeap.size=268435456\
        ./new.jar\
        /user/sclee/clustering2/mapTemplate_micron      /user/sclee/clustering2/data/bin3       /user/sclee/clustering2/ret
```

Comment: Did you configure Spark to read the HADOOP_CONF_DIR environment variable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks your `HADOOP_CONF_DIR` isn't loaded, or the files in it

For example, check this in the `spark-env.sh`, setting the correct directory for your config

```
HADOOP_CONF_DIR=/etc/hadoop/
```

Then, ensure that you have configured hdfs-site.xml, core-site.xml, and yarn-site.xml in that directory. (Although looks like you're not using YARN, so probably just the core and hdfs)